# Task Alignment Issue

Tags: alignment, tasks

I have not been able to figure out the alignment issue I am having. You can see the numbers are not quite aligned, most likely due to the display of the integrals.  Can anyone help me figure out how to align these?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}


% Edit these as appropriate
\newcommand\course{AP Calculus AB}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\headheight 35pt

\lfoot{Differentiation and Integration}
\chead{Cumulative Review \\ Differentiation and Integration}
\rhead{\course \\ \today}
\lfoot{AP Calculus AB}
\cfoot{Flint Hill}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\headsep 1em
\settasks{
    label-width=12pt,
    item-indent=3em,
    before-skip=0pt,
    after-skip=0pt,
    after-item-skip=0pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{tasks}
        \task[1. ] \;  \(f\big(x\big)=\big(2x+3\big)^3\cdot \cos x\), find \(f^\prime\) \\
        \task[2. ] \;  \(\displaystyle{\int \sin\big(4x\big)\; dx=}\) \\
        \task[3. ] \; If \(f\big(x\big)=e^{2x}\), then \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
        \task[4. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int\big(x^5-\sin x\big)\; dx=}\) \\
        \task[5. ] \; \(x^3+2xy+2y^2=90\), find \(dy/dx\) \\
        \task[6. ] \; \(f\big(x\big)=\sin^4\big(x^3\big)\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
        \task[7. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int\cos^5\big(x\big)\sin\big(x\big)\; dx=}\) \\
        \task[8. ] \; \(y=\big(x^2-3x\big)^6\) find \(y^\prime\) \\
        \task[9. ] \; \(y=\ln|\sin x|\) find \(y^\prime\) \\
        \task[10. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int 4x\cos\big(x^2\big)\;dx=}\) \\
        \task[11. ]  \; \(f\big(x\big)=e^{-x/2}\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
        \task[12. ]\;   \( y=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}\) find \(y^\prime\) \\
        \task[13. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int\big(x+2\big)\big(x^2+4x+11\big)\; dx}\) \\
        \task[14. ] \; \(y=\dfrac{8}{1+\cot x}\), find \(y^\prime\) \\
        \task[15. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int \sqrt[5]{3-5x}\; dx}\) \\
        \task[16.] \; \(\tan\big(x+y\big)=5x\) find \(dy/dx\) \\
        \task[17. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int 5\; dx}\) \\
        \task[18. ] \; \(y=\ln\sqrt{x^2-4}\) find \(y^\prime\) \\
        \task[19. ] \; \(f\big(x\big)=x^2e^x\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
        \task[20. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int x^3\big(1-x^2\big)\; dx}\) \\
        \task[21. ] \; \(f\big(x\big)=e^{\sin x}\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
        \task[22. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int\dfrac{1}{x^2}\; dx=}\)\\ 
        \task[23. ] \;  \(y=\sin^{-1}\big(7x\big)\), find \(y^\prime\) \\
        \task[24. ] \;  \(\displaystyle{\int 4\sec x\tan x\; dx=}\)\\
        \task[25. ] \;  \(f\big(x\big)=\ln\big|2x^3-5\big|\), find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
        \task[26. ]  \; \(\displaystyle{\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{11}}}\; dx}=\)\\
        \task[27. ]  \; \(\displaystyle{\int 2x\big(x^2+1\big)^2\; dx=}\)\\
        \task[28. ]  \; \(f\big(x\big)=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2\big(2x\big)\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\)\\
        \task[29. ]  \; \(f\big(x\big)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^3}\), find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\ 
        \task[30. ] \; \(f\big(x\big)=5e^{2-x}\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
        \task[31. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int x\big(60x^3-1\big)\; dx=}\) \\
        \task[32. ] \; \(f\big(x\big)=x^3\tan\big(5x\big)\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
        \task[33. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\int\Bigg(x^2-\dfrac{1}{x^3}\Bigg)\; dx=}\)\\
        \task[34. ] \; \(15\sec x\tan x\; dx=\) \\
        \task[35. ]\;\( f\big(x\big)=x\sqrt{x^3+2}\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\ 
        \task[36. ] \; \(y=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} \) find \(y^\prime\) \\
        \task[37. ] \; \(\displaystyle{\big(x+1\big)^2\; dx=}\) \\
        \task[38. ] \; \(f\big(x\big)=\tan^2\big(5x\big)\) find \(f^\prime\big(x\big)\) \\
    \end{tasks}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have on left column an integral on a line, it would probably help if you have on the right on the same line an integral, and same for fractions. Some tips for better code: replace `^\prime` by `'`, `\big(` and `\Bigg(` by `\left(`, `\big)` and `\Bigg)` by `\right)`, suppress all `[xx. ]`, and replace `\begin{task}` by `\begin{task}[label=\arabic*., label-align=right, label-offset=0.67em]` and increase the `label-width` dimension to something like `16pt`. Suppress all `\;` right after `\task`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the code with your suggestions. Still off with the numbers and columns.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want the numbering to go top-to-bottom and left-to-right rather than the more natural left-to-right and top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your problem stems from the integral signs, you can add `\vphantom{$\displaystyle$` to every item.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[
  top=1in,
  bottom=1.5in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  headsep=1em,
  headheight=35pt
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tasks}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}

% Edit these as appropriate
\newcommand\course{AP Calculus AB}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\lfoot{Differentiation and Integration}
\chead{Cumulative Review \\ Differentiation and Integration}
\rhead{\course \\ \today}
\lfoot{AP Calculus AB}
\cfoot{Flint Hill}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}

\settasks{
    label=\arabic*.,
    label-width=24pt,
    item-indent=3em,
    before-skip=0pt,
    after-skip=0pt,
    after-item-skip=12pt,
    item-format={\vphantom{$\displaystyle\int$}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tasks}(1)
  \task \(f(x)=(2x+3)^3\cdot \cos x\), find \(f'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int \sin(4x)\, dx=\) 
  \task If \(f(x)=e^{2x}\), then \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int(x^5-\sin x)\, dx=\) 
  \task \(x^3+2xy+2y^2=90\), find \(dy/dx\) 
  \task \(f(x)=\sin^4(x^3)\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int\cos^5(x)\sin(x)\, dx=\) 
  \task \(y=(x^2-3x)^6\) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(y=\ln|\sin x|\) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 4x\cos(x^2)\,dx=\) 
  \task \(f(x)=e^{-x/2}\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \( y=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}\) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int(x+2)(x^2+4x+11)\, dx\) 
  \task \(y=\dfrac{8}{1+\cot x}\), find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int \sqrt[5]{3-5x}\, dx\) 
  \task \(\tan(x+y)=5x\) find \(dy/dx\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 5\, dx\) 
  \task \(y=\ln\sqrt{x^2-4}\) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(f(x)=x^2e^x\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int x^3(1-x^2)\, dx\) 
  \task \(f(x)=e^{\sin x}\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int\dfrac{1}{x^2}\, dx=\) 
  \task \(y=\sin^{-1}(7x)\), find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 4\sec x\tan x\, dx=\)
  \task \(f(x)=\ln\big|2x^3-5\big|\), find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{11}}}\, dx=\)
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 2x(x^2+1)^2\, dx=\)
  \task \(f(x)=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2(2x)\) find \(f'(x)\)
  \task \(f(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^3}\), find \(f'(x)\)  
  \task \(f(x)=5e^{2-x}\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int x(60x^3-1)\, dx=\) 
  \task \(f(x)=x^3\tan(5x)\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int\Bigl(x^2-\dfrac{1}{x^3}\Bigr)\, dx=\)
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 15\sec x\tan x\, dx=\) 
  \task \( f(x)=x\sqrt{x^3+2}\) find \(f'(x)\)  
  \task \(y=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} \) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int(x+1)^2\, dx=\) 
  \task \(f(x)=\tan^2(5x)\) find \(f'(x)\) 
\end{tasks}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Note that I vastly simplified your code:

1. no `\big` is used, because parentheses are already the right size
2. `^\prime` is better input as `'`
3. no manual numbering, as `tasks` is able to do it by itself
4. all `\;` have been removed, but replaced by `\,` in front of `dx`
5. instead of `\Bigg`, I used `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` (the smaller the fences, the better)
6. all `\\` have been removed as useless, replaced by a fixed separation between items
7. `\displaystyle` doesn't take an argument

[image]

On the other hand, I see no reason for this peculiar ordering (top-to-bottom and left-to-right) instead of the more natural left-to-right and top-to-bottom.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[
  top=1in,
  bottom=1.5in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  headsep=1em,
  headheight=35pt
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tasks}
%\usepackage{parskip}
%\usepackage{multicol}

% Edit these as appropriate
\newcommand\course{AP Calculus AB}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\lfoot{Differentiation and Integration}
\chead{Cumulative Review \\ Differentiation and Integration}
\rhead{\course \\ \today}
\lfoot{AP Calculus AB}
\cfoot{Flint Hill}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}

\settasks{
    label=\arabic*.,
    label-width=24pt,
    item-indent=3em,
    before-skip=0pt,
    after-skip=0pt,
    after-item-skip=12pt,
    item-format={\vphantom{$\displaystyle\int$}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tasks}(2)
  \task \(f(x)=(2x+3)^3\cdot \cos x\), find \(f'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int \sin(4x)\, dx=\) 
  \task If \(f(x)=e^{2x}\), then \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int(x^5-\sin x)\, dx=\) 
  \task \(x^3+2xy+2y^2=90\), find \(dy/dx\) 
  \task \(f(x)=\sin^4(x^3)\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int\cos^5(x)\sin(x)\, dx=\) 
  \task \(y=(x^2-3x)^6\) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(y=\ln|\sin x|\) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 4x\cos(x^2)\,dx=\) 
  \task \(f(x)=e^{-x/2}\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \( y=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}\) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int(x+2)(x^2+4x+11)\, dx\) 
  \task \(y=\dfrac{8}{1+\cot x}\), find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int \sqrt[5]{3-5x}\, dx\) 
  \task \(\tan(x+y)=5x\) find \(dy/dx\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 5\, dx\) 
  \task \(y=\ln\sqrt{x^2-4}\) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(f(x)=x^2e^x\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int x^3(1-x^2)\, dx\) 
  \task \(f(x)=e^{\sin x}\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int\dfrac{1}{x^2}\, dx=\) 
  \task \(y=\sin^{-1}(7x)\), find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 4\sec x\tan x\, dx=\)
  \task \(f(x)=\ln\big|2x^3-5\big|\), find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{11}}}\, dx=\)
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 2x(x^2+1)^2\, dx=\)
  \task \(f(x)=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2(2x)\) find \(f'(x)\)
  \task \(f(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^3}\), find \(f'(x)\)  
  \task \(f(x)=5e^{2-x}\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int x(60x^3-1)\, dx=\) 
  \task \(f(x)=x^3\tan(5x)\) find \(f'(x)\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int\Bigl(x^2-\dfrac{1}{x^3}\Bigr)\, dx=\)
  \task \(\displaystyle \int 15\sec x\tan x\, dx=\) 
  \task \( f(x)=x\sqrt{x^3+2}\) find \(f'(x)\)  
  \task \(y=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} \) find \(y'\) 
  \task \(\displaystyle \int(x+1)^2\, dx=\) 
  \task \(f(x)=\tan^2(5x)\) find \(f'(x)\) 
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I first set it up it automatically used letters for "numbering" so i just added the brackets [number] to correct it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a code that meet your requirements :

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multicol}


% Edit these as appropriate
\newcommand\course{AP Calculus AB}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\headheight 35pt

\lfoot{Differentiation and Integration}
\chead{Cumulative Review \\ Differentiation and Integration}
\rhead{\course \\ \today}
\lfoot{AP Calculus AB}
\cfoot{Flint Hill}
\rfoot{\small\thepage}
\headsep 1em
\settasks{
    label-width=16pt,
    item-indent=3em,
    before-skip=0pt,
    after-skip=0pt,
    after-item-skip=0pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{tasks}[label=\arabic*., label-align=right, label-offset=0.67em]
        \task  $f\left(x\right)=\left(2x+3\right)^3\cdot \cos x$, find $f'$ \\ 
        \task  $\displaystyle{\int \sin\left(4x\right)\; dx=}$ \\ 
        \task If $f\left(x\right)=e^{2x}$, then $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int\left(x^5-\sin x\right)\; dx=}$ \\
        \task $x^3+2xy+2y^2=90$, find $dy/dx$ \\
        \task $f\left(x\right)=\sin^4\left(x^3\right)$ find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int\cos^5\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)\; dx=}$ \\
        \task $y=\left(x^2-3x\right)^6$ find $y'$ \\
        \task $y=\ln|\sin x|$ find $y'$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int 4x\cos\left(x^2\right)\;dx=}$ \\
        \task   $f\left(x\right)=e^{-x/2}$ find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task   $ y=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ find $y'$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int\left(x+2\right)\left(x^2+4x+11\right)\; dx}$ \\
        \task $y=\dfrac{8}{1+\cot x}$, find $y'$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int \sqrt[5]{3-5x}\; dx}$ \\
        \task $\tan\left(x+y\right)=5x$ find $dy/dx$ \\
        \task $y=\ln\sqrt{x^2-4}$ find $y'$ \\
        \task $f\left(x\right)=x^2e^x$ find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int 5\; dx}$ \\
        \task $f\left(x\right)=e^{\sin x}$ find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int x^3\left(1-x^2\right)\; dx}$ \\
        \task  $y=\sin^{-1}\left(7x\right)$, find $y'$ \\
        \task  $f\left(x\right)=\ln\left|2x^3-5\right|$, find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task  $\displaystyle{\int 4\sec x\tan x\; dx=}$\\
        \task $\displaystyle{\left(x+1\right)^2\; dx=}$ \\
        \task $f\left(x\right)=\tan^2\left(5x\right)$ find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int\dfrac{1}{x^2}\; dx=}$\\ 
        \task $f\left(x\right)=5e^{2-x}$ find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task  $f\left(x\right)=\dfrac{e^x}{x^3}$, find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\ 
        \task $\displaystyle{\int x\left(60x^3-1\right)\; dx=}$ \\
        \task   $f\left(x\right)=\dfrac{1}{4}\sin^2\left(2x\right)$ find $f'\left(x\right)$\\
        \task  $\displaystyle{\int 2x\left(x^2+1\right)^2\; dx=}$\\
        \task $15\sec x\tan x\; dx=$ \\
        \task $ f\left(x\right)=x\sqrt{x^3+2}$ find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\ 
        \task $y=\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} $ find $y'$ \\
        \task  $\displaystyle{\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x^{11}}}\; dx}=$\\
        \task $f\left(x\right)=x^3\tan\left(5x\right)$ find $f'\left(x\right)$ \\
        \task $\displaystyle{\int\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{x^3}\right)\; dx=}$\\

    \end{tasks}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Not totally perfect if you look with a magnify glass, but probably more aligned than the previous code.

Comparison:

[image]

Comment: thank you for taking time to help.